# Is there a way integrate redactor with your assets fields?

Tags: redactor, plugin-redactorstyles

Does anyone know if there is a way to extend redactor to render a template, for example, when inserting an image so that it could also display custom asset fields (i.e. caption, photo credit, etc.) in a small html block? I have no idea how difficult or easy it is write redactor plugins.

Comment: This is a use case I'm looking to address with [ImageSmith](http://michaelrog.com/craft/imagesmith)'s bulk transform capabilities. Shoot me a note if you'd like to get on the best test list.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to tackle something like this would be to use a matrix instead of just a rich text area.

With a matrix you can have an image block and then in your template you can pull any info you want from the images custom fields.

We normally have at least three block types with a normal matrix, text, image, and gallery.

Text is just a refactor text block.  Image is an image with a "position" field to control alignment (float left/right/center) the a gallery block which lets you select a series of images which display in a slideshow

Comment: Thanks Keith. This is definitely a good option and one I've considered. However, in this case images are quite rare and the articles are really really long. I would prefer to keep it simple, so that they can just copy paste the whole article then go back and insert an image or two, but still include the image caption and or photo credit.