# Adding alt tag to an image

Tags: redactor

All of my assets have fields for alt text and I understand how to access that info from an asset field, but can not figure out how to do it when an image has been inserted using Redactor.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: If you haven't already, I would recommend taking a look into Matrix fields: http://buildwithcraft.com/features/matrix. This would allow you to create your own custom content blocks (text, image etc), and assign fields to these. So you can create an image block, and in there have a plain text field that sets the alt tag for the image.

Answer (score 3):

For `alt` tag content you can just click the image in the richtext field, hit the 'edit' button and add a title.

As far as I know there is no way to integrate an `alt` text field (or any other fields) from assets without writing a custom redactor plugin. I posted a [similar question here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4559/is-there-a-way-integrate-redactor-with-your-assets-fields) and the only solution was to use a matrix field instead. But I too would love to hear about any other options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply can't set it from the redactor editor. But because asset meta fields are saved "globally" and not "per entry", you can enter the content from the CP's assets section.

But that probably won't help you much, because there's no out-of-box solution to output the fields data in your template. You would need to extent Redactor with a plugin and I'm not sure if you can modify how images are handled.

But like Douglas said, the best solution around this is to use Matrix instead.

Comment: Thanks, but Matrix is not really a good solution here because I want to be able to add any number of images in various places within the text body.

Comment: Why do you think Matrix doesn't allow you to do that? Just add one "Text" block with a Redactor field and one "Images" block with an assets field. Start writing with a "Text" block and stop at that position of your article where you want one or multiple images to be and add a new "images" block. Then add another "Text" block to continue writing, @RoiAgneta!

Comment: That's just the basic version, but you could add fields to your "Images" to change size, position etc. of that block's images. Or add another block type for "Quotes" for example.